# Inserting a PHP variable in an HTML string being passed to JavaScript function via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is something like this:

```
$html .= "<table>"
$html .= "<tr onclick=\"test(" . $phpvar . ")\"><td>test</td></tr>";
$html .= "</table>"

$rVal=array("htmltable" => $html);
echo json_encode($rVal);
```

JS:

```
success: function(data){
    $("#content").html(data.htmltable);
```

possible?

Everything works when no PHP var is involved, but I'm asking if there's a way to pass a PHP var like this ...

Comment: What is the value of the variable? What does the resulting JavaScript you are generating look like? Is it correct?

Comment: It's correct (functioning without error) ... the value of $phpvar is a string of a person's first and last name, and nickname ... the test(x) JS function is an alert

Comment: Don't do this. Really. Don't do this. Don't use tables for layout. Don't use inline event handlers. Don't generate JavaScript nested inside HTML nested inside PHP. It will give you a headache. The response you send to the Ajax request should be the data you care about. Generate the markup on the client. e.g. `success: function(data) {
 $("#content").empty().append($("<button />").text("test").on("click", function() {
   test(data.htmltable);
  });
 });
}`

Comment: work if $phpvar is boolean or number... if is a string need to wrap beetween quotes

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's correct (functioning without error) ... the value of $phpvar is a string of a person's first and last name, and nickname

So given:

```
$phpvar = "John 'the Something' Smith";
```

The value of `$html` will be:

```
<table><tr onclick="test(John 'the Something' Smith)"><td>test</td></tr></table>
```

So `John` will be treated as a JavaScript variable name. Then you'll hit a syntax error.

You need to encode the data as a JavaScript string literal. `json_encode` will do that.

```
$phpvar = "John 'the Something' Smith";

$javascript_literal = json_encode($phpvar);

$html = "";
$html .= "<table>";
$html .= "<tr onclick=\"test(" . $javascript_literal . ")\"><td>test</td></tr>";
$html .= "</table>";

print $html;
```

… but that still won't work because it will give you:

```
<table><tr onclick="test("John 'the Something' Smith")"><td>test</td></tr></table>
```

… and the `"` will terminate the attribute value.

So you also need to encode it for HTML.

```
$phpvar = "John 'the Something' Smith";

$javascript_literal = json_encode($phpvar);

$html_attribute_value = htmlspecialchars($javascript_literal);

$html = "";
$html .= "<table>";
$html .= "<tr onclick=\"test(" . $html_attribute_value . ")\"><td>test</td></tr>";
$html .= "</table>";

print $html;
```

which will give you:

```
<table><tr onclick="test(&quot;John 'the Something' Smith&quot;)"><td>test</td></tr></table>
```

… which will work.

---

But that is horrible. And headache inducing. So don't do that.

- Pass data back to the client instead of markup.
- Use appropriate markup for the task. You want something to click on? Use a button. Not a table.

Such:

```
$rVal = array("plaindata" => $phpvar);
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($rVal);
```

and

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#content")
        .empty()
        .append(
            $("<button />")
                .text("test")
                .on("click", function() { test(data.plaindata); })
         );
}
```